# IEnumerable<T> to IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, type-conversion, idictionary

What's the most efficient way to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>`

Where U is, for example a Guid, for which the information is held in a property of T.

Basically, this creates a dictionary of lists where all items in the original list are grouped based on a value in a property within the objects.

**EXAMPLE**

Object Definition:

```
class myObject
{
    public Guid UID { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Start with:

```
IEnumerable<myObject> listOfObj;
```

End with:

```
IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<myObject>> dictOfLists;
```

Whereby `listOfObj` contains objects that have many different, but sometimes overlapping values for the UID property.

Comment: Your explanation is slightly confusing. Maybe if you provide an example it would clear things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var dict = input.GroupBy(elem => elem.Identifier)
                .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => grouping.Select(x => x));
```

Comment: This builds an `IDictionary<U, IGrouping<U, T>>` which isn't exactly the same as `IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: Or use `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.Select()`. Or just cast `grouping` since `IGrouping<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: `AsEnumerable` evaluates the collection immediately, while `Select` remains deferred - so `Select` is preferable, also casting doesn't change the type like `Select` - the caller could still cast it back, which isn't the behaviour you want either.

Comment: @Femaref - I just tested it, and `AsEnumerable` is **definitely** deferred.

Comment: Oh, I mixed that one up - yes it is deferred as it justs returns the incoming sequence. However, this would still enable the caller to cast it back to whatever implementation (`IGrouping` or similar) was used, which you definitely don't want.

Comment: Some might definitely not want that, but personally I can't imagine caring, for this particular case.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I wouldn't do it either in this case. However you should know about such things, especially if you were to expose public APIs and without projecting it, you could offer your inner implementation to the outside.

Answer (score 2):

The *most* efficient way to *convert* is definitely writing an implementation of `IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>` interface, which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` in the constructor, and implements all the operations on the fly using lookups into the given `IEnumerable<T>`. This way the conversion itself is O(1).

However such an implementation would have not a good performance (but this is unrelated to the conversion efficiency).

Comment: Thanks - I like the idea here as well... I'm worried about the performance after the conversion though.

Answer (score 2):

An `ILookup<U,T>` as a "collection of keys mapped to one or more values" is not identical to an `IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>` but it is equivalent, and in some ways better. It's certainly easy to create:

```
var myLookup = listOfObj.ToLookup(x => x.UID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like:

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(i => i.Guid,
                              (guid, i) => new { Key = guid, i })
                     .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i);
```

This would group the original list on common Guids and then give you a dictionary with that Guid as the key.

Comment: This builds an `IDictionary<U, IGrouping<U, T>>` which isn't exactly the same as `IDictionary<U, IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: @Remus - While it's not the prettiest, the code above should work as expected.